# Ionic 5 Angular: How to clear capacitor storage on app uninstall?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I have the problem that after uninstalling and reinstalling my app, the Capacitor Storage data from the uninstalled app is still available.

I use the standard [Storage-Plugin of Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/storage/). They say "Stored data is cleared if the app is uninstalled." But that's not the case with me on android.

How can Capacitor Storage be cleared when I uninstall an app?

Many thanks!

Comment: I have found that Capacitor Storage data is actually cleared when app is uninstalled, both on Android and iOS. Do you have a repo to replicate? Is the app published on Google Play?

Comment: Unfortunately i connot install the app ("not available in your country").

Comment: Right, the app is only available in Germany. I just tested it: 

The app only clears memory when uninstalling if the app is installed from the Google play store. If I install the app from Android Studio on my device, the data is not deleted during uninstallation.

Comment: @Sébastien: Does it work for you also in the emulator or if you install the app via Android-Studio on your device?

Comment: I use Android Studio and I have 2 real Android test devices. In my experience, uninstalling the app remove all storage. You may have to "uninstall for all users" if you have guest accounts configured on the device.

Comment: I have the same problem. Deleting the app and downloading the app from PlayStore (internal test) shows the old data, which is a huge problem, because I reseted the test database. Now my customer have key contraint exceptions..

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very late answer, this answer may be helpful to other people like me.

Add **`android:allowBackup="false"`** in application tab in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. It was true in my case, so the storage variable was returning true even after uninstalling the application.